# Proper use of delete in c++

Tags: c++, new-operator, delete-operator

First of all I am sorry for this question. I have looked at most of the major answers related to `delete` and `new` in C++ but I am still unable to correct my problems here.
Here I have 3 classes as follows:

```
class bucket
{
    // Some stl container here where data would be inserted
    // Some methods and fields here
    // This class has no new keyword
};

class TrieNode
{
   public:
   bucket *pointer;
    TrieNode() //Constructor for this class
    {
        pointer = NULL;
    };
    TrieNode(int local)  //Parametrized Constructor for this class
    {
        pointer = new bucket(local); //Here is the new keyword
    }
};

class Hashtable
{
   private:
    int globalDepth;
    std::vector<TrieNode> table; //Vector of other class 

  void Split(int index)
  {
    // Here I am creating instances of other class(TrieNode) which has pointer
      TrieNode first(capacity); 
      TrieNode second(capacity);
   // Then after some processing I have to do this
      table[index] = first; //Assignment which will be using new keyword in it's class i.e. first
      table[mirrorIndex] = second; //again assignment
  }
 public:
  Hashtable(int globalDepth) //Constructor for this class
  {
      std::cout<<"Table is being created...\n";
      this->globalDepth = globalDepth;
      table.resize(pow(2,globalDepth),TrieNode()); //vector of class here 
  }
};

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    bool input = true;
    Hashtable mytable(1); //Instance of Third class
}
```

> Now my problem is when I use destructor in class `TrieNode` with `delete pointer` it shows me segmentation fault as soon as I try to insert something in the vector of class C because destructor is called automatically after the creation and it deletes the vector [right?] and when I use `delete` in the class C destructor as `delete table[i].pointer`then I get the error too [core dumped]. So how should I use `delete` in these cases. Cases where I have used assignment of a class instance (with new) inside some functions for e.g. in Split function above in class C Or should I change the overall style here?

Comment: Learn to use gdb and read about std::unique_ptr and copy constructors (what they actually copy)

Comment: @James  Sure. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A `TrieNode` instance owns its `pointer` instance of type `bucket`, so it is responsible for freeing it by calling `delete` in the destructor.  So first you need to add something like:

```
~TrieNode()
{
    delete pointer;
}
```

(Note that `pointer` is probably not a great name for a variable, since it is indicative of its type rather than its usage. Consider `data` or something.)

Then whenever the `TrieNode` is deleted, so too will its bucket pointer. You can call `delete` safely on `nullptr` and it will simply do nothing, so there's no need to test if `pointer` is set.

Since the hash table uses instances of `std::vector<TrieNode>`, the vector will contain (and own) the object instances. Thus removing an instance, deleting the `HashTable` etc should all clean up correctly.

One potential problem is if you create an instance of `TrieNode` and then pass it in to the `HashTable`. This will make a shallow copy of the object (since you have not defined a copy constructor) and thus you will have two objects pointing to the same bucket on the heap. When the first instance is destroyed, the bucket will be deleted. But then when the second instance is destroyed, it will likewise try to delete the bucket a second time, and cause a crash.  I suspect this explains the crashing problems you describe.

In general, if your class dynamically allocates memory, it should have a destructor and a copy constructor so that memory is managed correctly.  Try to make new/delete work symmetrically, so the thing that owns the memory (calls `new`) also `delete`s it. The hash table should not "reach in" to the trie object and delete the memory on its behalf.

As @James commented above, it's probably worth using smart pointers and letting the compiler and library do the work for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
class TrieNode
{
   public:
   bucket *pointer;
    TrieNode() //Constructor for this class
    {
        pointer = NULL;
    }
    ~TrieNode() //destructor for this class
    {
        pointer = NULL;
delete pointer;
    }
    TrieNode(int local)  //Parametrized Constructor for this class
    {
        pointer = new bucket(local); //Here is the new keyword
    }
};
```

Where did you define capacity ?
There is a ';' after your constructor definition which i removed.
The destructor of your class simply needs to delete the object allocated on the heap with new, the compiler will take care of destroying all local variables, you only worry about what is heap allocated.

```
 Hashtable(int nGlobalDepth) //Constructor for this class
  {
      std::cout<<"Table is being created...\n";
      this->globalDepth = nGlobalDepth;
      table.resize(pow(2,globalDepth),TrieNode()); //vector of class here 
  }
```

Having a variable with the exact same name both as a class member and as a function argument using the specified class member is bad practice, you have several options (could use the '_' prefix to class member variable or rename the argument)

Comment: I have not shown the full code of all the classes and methods. `capacity` is one `int` defined within the method. I will check this code and reply you as soon as I am done. Thanks by the way and one question why are you making `pointer NULL` and then `deleting` it. What purpose will  it serve?

Comment: Using your suggestion in a vector will break, since the TrieNode does not comply with rule-of-three